# Knockout: filling observable with an email produces [object HTMLinput] output

Tags: javascript, forms, knockout.js

I have a string `"admin@admin.ru"` that I take out of cookies.

I have a model

```
var LoginModel = function () {
        this.authEmail = ko.observable("");
        this.authPassword = ko.observable("");
    };
var ajaxLoginModel = new LoginModel();
```

I do

```
ajaxLoginModel.authEmail("admin@admin.ru");
```

It works fine, but in the input element in looks like this
[image]

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form-ajaxLogin">
        <fieldset>
            <h4 align="center">Пожалуйста, авторизуйтесь.</h4>
            <div class="control-group" align="center">
                <label class="control-label control-label-120" for="authEmail">E-mail</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="authEmail" class="input-xlarge required email" id="authEmail" data-bind="value: authEmail,  valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group" align="center">
                <label class="control-label control-label-120" for="authPassword">Пароль</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" name="authPassword" class="input-xlarge" id="authPassword" data-bind="value: authPassword,  valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Full screenshot: http://i.gyazo.com/473b9d9a80113dee5fdcd80d8adacd50.png

Comment: What does you binding look like? Include the HTML for it. Because it works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LvHwq/)

Comment: @MattBurland, added html to OP.

Comment: Still works [fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/LvHwq/1/). You must have something else going on.

Comment: What browser are you using? Can you please provide a full screenshot?

Comment: @WayneEllery, chrome. Yes, sure.

Comment: @Euphe: The fiddle I posted works fine. So whatever is causing your problem is coming from somewhere else and I don't think anybody is going to be able to just guess. Start with what's working and add back parts from your real application until it breaks. That should help you find what's causing the problem.

Comment: It may be worth considering the version of KO. The fiddle is using 3.0, and the issue here may not exist in that version.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar once upon a time, and although I cannot remember the specifics, your issue may be resolved by changing or removing the `id` or `name` attributes of the authEmail input element (I cannot remember which). Alternatively you may change the name of the observable to something other than authEmail.